# Is Janet van Dyne’s movie storyline similar to any comics?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-2015, the-wasp

Janet van Dyne AKA The Wasp, once the wife of Hank Pym, made her MCU debut in a flashback sequence alongside Pym during his time as the original Ant-Man.

> She was lost when she pushed her powered suit too far and shrunk down to sub-atomic size in order to pass through metal and save Pym.

How does this compare to her written/drawn history? Was this event created solely for the MCU, or does it have a basis in any comic stories?

Furthermore, if it does, do those stories show her

> returning after being lost?

Comment: “is there any way to predict the further storyline involving her as far as the MCU is concerned?” Sure! You just have to predict [what Andrew Barrer, Gabriel Ferrari and Paul Rudd will write over the next year or so](http://www.comingsoon.net/movies/news/639769-ant-man-and-the-wasp-recruits-two-writers). If you do figure it out, please let them know so that they can put their feet up.

Comment: I meant so far as the spoiler-hidden scenario is concerned, and any possible escape from said scenario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the Wasp was trapped in the Microverse for a time and thought dead by her teammates. A good rundown of her apparent death and later return can be found [here](https://www.cbr.com/the-abandoned-an-forsaked-so-did-wasp-die-or-what/).

In short, at the end of the Secret Invasion storyline it was revealed that the Wasp had been infected by the Skrulls with a virus that turned her into a bomb. She seemed to die as a result of this. It was later revealed that she instinctually shrank down to get away and spare her teammates, and found herself trapped in the Microverse where she remained until the Avengers found and rescued her.